# TortoiseHg: Delete files that are ignored

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I'm using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) for mercurial repositories. Of course, I exclude directories, such as

- bin
- obj
- Debug
- Release
- *.suo
- And so on...

Over time, when I open solutions from the repository, these directories get created by Visual Studio. I want to get rid of them because I also keep backups of my hard drive and these directories increase its size, especially the C++ **sdf**-file!

[image]

**What I've tried**

I tried the **purge** extension. But this apparently seems to just delete empty directories and has nothing to do with the `.hgignore` file.

**Question:** How can I delete all files that are covered by `.hgignore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hg purge` deletes untracked files.  `hg purge --all` deletes ignored files as well.  Since an ignored directory ignores all the files under it, it will delete that directory.